# How to set background colour using NativeScript theme v3

Tags: themes, nativescript

I am trying to work out how to use `NativeScript` theme v3 and am stuck on something so simple as setting the background colour according to theme:

Here's what I'm trying (using the [recommended `colorize` mixin](https://github.com/NativeScript/theme)):

```
@import "~@nativescript/theme/scss/variables";

.mything {
    @include colorize($background-color: primary);
}
```

But this always just sets the background dark and has no effect when I switch theme.

If I try the following code it is always red, also following the recommended approach:

```
.mything {
    background-color: red;
    .ns-dark & {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have [just found a solution of sorts](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/dark-mode#how-does-it-work) that solves the issue, in that I am able to make it work when I switch themes - however this seems to defeat the point of having the `colorize` mixins etc.

```
.mything {
    background-color: red;
}

:host-context(.ns-dark) .mything {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Or:

```
.mything {
    background-color: red;
    :host-context(.ns-dark) & {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

I am posting this here in case anybody else struggles with this and nobody else answers.